# Why am I leaking memory with this python loop?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, glob

I am writing a custom file system crawler, which gets passed millions of globs to process through sys.stdin. I'm finding that when running the script, its memory usage increases massively over time and the whole thing crawls practically to a halt. I've written a minimal case below which shows the problem. Am I doing something wrong, or have I found a bug in Python / the glob module? (I am using python 2.5.2).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob
import sys
import gc

previous_num_objects = 0

for count, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
   glob_result = glob.glob(line.rstrip('\n'))
   current_num_objects = len(gc.get_objects())
   new_objects = current_num_objects - previous_num_objects

   print "(%d) This: %d, New: %d, Garbage: %d, Collection Counts: %s"\
 % (count, current_num_objects, new_objects, len(gc.garbage), gc.get_count())
   previous_num_objects = current_num_objects
```

The output looks like:

```
(0) This: 4042, New: 4042, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (660, 5, 0)
(1) This: 4061, New: 19, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (90, 6, 0)
(2) This: 4064, New: 3, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (127, 6, 0)
(3) This: 4067, New: 3, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (130, 6, 0)
(4) This: 4070, New: 3, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (133, 6, 0)
(5) This: 4073, New: 3, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (136, 6, 0)
(6) This: 4076, New: 3, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (139, 6, 0)
(7) This: 4079, New: 3, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (142, 6, 0)
(8) This: 4082, New: 3, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (145, 6, 0)
(9) This: 4085, New: 3, Python Garbage: 0, Python Collection Counts: (148, 6, 0)
```

Every 100th iteration, 100 objects are freed, so `len(gc.get_objects()` increases by 200 every 100 iterations. `len(gc.garbage)` never changes from 0. The 2nd generation collection count increases slowly, while the 0th and 1st counts go up and down.

Comment: This accumulates a lot of uncollected objects.  However, this doesn't slow to a halt, does it?  Can you work up a similar small script that actually crawls to a halt?

Answer (score 7):

I tracked this down to the fnmatch module. glob.glob calls fnmatch to actually perform the globbing, and fnmatch has a cache of regular expressions which is never cleared. So in this usage, the cache was growing continuously and unchecked. I've filed a bug against the fnmatch library [1].

[1]: http://bugs.python.org/issue7846 Python Bug

Comment: I wonder how I managed to spot the similar cache in the re module but not this one! Perhaps I should subtract a point from my own answer for that...

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce any actual leak on my system, but I think your "every 100th iteration, 100 objects are freed" is you hitting the cache for compiled regular expressions (via the glob module). If you peek at re.py you'll see `_MAXCACHE` defaults to 100, and by default the entire cache is blown away once you hit that (in `_compile`). If you call `re.purge()` before your `gc` calls you will probably see that effect go away.

(note I'm only suggesting `re.purge()` here to check that cache is affecting your gc results. It should not be necessary to have that in your actual code.)

I doubt that fixes your massive memory increase problem though.

Comment: Thanks for this - when I did what you suggested, the effect indeed went away, and the new objects per loop changed to 2. It doesn't fix the memory increase problem, but it's certainly going to help understand what's going on.